# Function to put ' ' after n symbols

Tags: c, arrays, string, dynamic

I need to write function that every n position assigns with empty character. Now i have smth like that, but it isn't work as i want)

```
void strEscape(char* string, int length,int param) {
    int count = 0; // tried to count how many times , inserted ' '
    for (int i = 1; i + count < length; i++) {
        if (i%param==0) { // checking if reached n position
            length++;
            string = (char*)realloc(string, (length+1) * sizeof(char));
            for (int j = length; j > i; j--) {
                string[j] = string[j-1]; //swapping elements
            }

            string[i+count] = ' '; 
            string[length] = '\0';
            count++;
        }
    }

}
```

For example lets take that i want to put ' ' after 3 symbols, so param = 3;

And that's results, what i have now

Input->Output:

abca->abc a

abcabca-> abc abc a

abcabcabca -> abc abc abb aa -> here smth going wrong

And i have a (HEAP[Source.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap) if string contains 10 and more elements

Comment: Please demonstrate your problem with a [mre].

Comment: This `int &length` not so C-ish.

Comment: Pass by reference parameter is not possible in C.

Comment: The new value of `string` will be lost on function exit, with a memory leak, and the value of the pointer variable passed will (likely) no longer be valid. You can have a `char **string` or you can give the function a type to return, such as `char *strEscape`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can do it.

```
void strEscape(char** pstr, int len, int param) {

    if(param <= 0 || param >= len) {
        return;
    }
    // required length of new string
    int new_len = len + (len-1)/param;

    // allocate memory for new string
    char* new_str = malloc(new_len * sizeof(char) + 1);

    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while(j < new_len) {
        if(i > 0 && i%param == 0) {
            new_str[j++] = ' ';
        }
        new_str[j] = (*pstr)[i];
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    new_str[j] = '\0';

    // free old string
    free(*pstr);
    // assign pstr to point to new string
    *pstr = new_str;
}

int main() {
    char* str = "abcdabcdabcd";
    // pstr is pointer to string str
    char** pstr = &str;
    strEscape(pstr, 12, 3);
    printf("%s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```